# Loops not working in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I originally wrote this program in python 2, and it worked fine, then I switched over to python 3, and the while loop working.

I don't get any errors when I run the program, but it isnt checking for what the value of i is before or during the run. The while loop and the first if loop will run no matter what.

```
#imports the random module
import random

#Creates variable that is used later
i = 0

#chooses a random number betweeen 1 - 100
randomNumber = random.randint(1,10)

#prints the number
print (randomNumber)

#Creates while loop that runs the program until number is guessed
while i == 0:

    #Creates a variable where the answer will be stored, and then asked the question in the quotes
    user_answer = input("Try to guess the magic number. (1 - 10) ")

    print ("\n")

    if user_answer == randomNumber:
        print("You guessed correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect. Try again.")
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "First if loop"?

Comment: `input` returns a **string**, not an integer.

Comment: `input` has been updated in python3 to no longer try to treat the input as a python expression, meaning that while `user_answer` in python2 would be an integer if they input something that looks like an integer, it will in python3 always be a string. That just means you'll need to cast it to an integer before comparing it to `randomNumber`

Comment: Also, why are you checking on `i` and then breaking? Why not incorporate your condition *into* the loop .

Comment: I forgot to change the break to i = 1

Comment: In python 2 you should be using `raw_input`, not `input`

Comment: That's even worse.  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻)

Comment: You have to do something like `user_answer = int(input("Try to guess the magic number. (1 - 10) "))` to make sure you're comparing integer to integer, you may wish to place it in `try:  ..  except ValueError:` block.

Comment: Casting it to an integer fixed the problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: you might wanna use try-except because the user might provide values that are not integer

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing something like `'6' == 6`, since you didn't convert the user input to an `int`.

Replace `user_answer = input("Try to guess the magic number. (1 - 10) ")` with `user_answer = int(input("Try to guess the magic number. (1 - 10) "))`.

Comment: that fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`user_answer` will store the input as string and `random.randint(1,10)` will return an integer. An integer will never be equal to a string. So you need to convert user_input to integer before checking.

```
#imports the random module
import random

#Creates variable that is used later
i = 0

#chooses a random number betweeen 1 - 100
randomNumber = random.randint(1,10)

#prints the number
print (randomNumber)

#Creates while loop that runs the program until number is guessed
while i == 0:

    #Creates a variable where the answer will be stored, and then 
    asked the question in the quotes
    user_answer = input("Try to guess the magic number. (1 - 10) ")

    # better use exception handling here
    try:
        user_answer = int(user_answer)
    except:
        pass

    print ("\n")

    if user_answer == randomNumber:
        print("You guessed correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect. Try again.")
```